# Convert Linq statement to be used in abstracted repository pattern

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, repository-pattern

This Linq statement works perfectly except that I realized that I am required to use the repository and unit of work ...

So I have this Linq query

```
var query = (from rg in ReportGroups  
                join rd in ReportDefinitions on rg.ReportGroupID equals rd.ReportGroupID
                where rd.ReportGroupID == 5
                select rg).Count();
```

What I am seeing is that

1. ReportGroups  uses  GetReportGroups   ( for GetAll() )
2. ReportDefinitions uses  GetReportDefinitions  (for GetAll() )

So an example is

```
 object responseObject = null;
 responseObject = _reportService.GetReportGroups("en-us").ToList();
 responseObject = _reportService.GetReportDefinitions("en-us").Where(e => e.ReportGroupID == Convert.ToInt32(id)).ToList();
```

So you can see that is how I'm currently having to retrieve data.

I am wanting to do a Join, but i'm not sure how I can do this.

I was thinking about multiple calls,  many a for loop...

Also I noticed how an existing service is called in a different method with lambda statement

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetActivityList()
    {
        return _activityService
            .GetAllActivities()
            .OrderBy(n => n.ActivityName)
            .Select(a => new SelectListItem
                         {
                             Text = a.ActivityName,
                             Value = a.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                         });
    }
```

I realize that people cannot see all the underlying data abstractions, and I can certainly provide anything asked,  I'm just a bit stumped as I used Linqpad to connect to the database and wrote my query, but now I realize that the join etc.. is maybe not so easy with the service layers.

Answer (score 0):

```
  return DbSet.Include(x => x.ReportGroups  )
            .Include(x => x.ReportDefinitions ).Where(//id condition);
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Comment: Include gets both tables ,You can get the details you want by giving your condition

Comment: I'm not sure how to use DbSet like this   ,   so if I swap that out  it does not like Include  and then the ReportGroups and ReportDefinitions are a problem too      return _reportService.Include(x => x.ReportGroups)
            .Include(x => x.ReportDefinitions).Where(id);

Comment: the condition is valid if Report Definitions is a foreign key for ReportGroups and you have to give x.id==33